# Angular Adding a Row with the Same Properties

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my app, I have a data table and a copyWorkItem button next to every row. I want the user to add a row with the same properties when he clicks the button next to a row. My code is below and I currently get some errors. How should I fix my code?

HTML:

```
            <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="userRights.CanChangeWorkItem && isInEditableState"
            (click)="copyWorkItem(i)">
            <mat-icon>warning</mat-icon>
        </button>
```

TS:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IWorkItem>;
    copyWorkItem(index: number){
        let item: IWorkItem = {};
        let tempData = this.dataSource.data.splice(0);
        tempData.unshift(item);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tempData);
        this.EditIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: could you please provide the errors you are getting?

Comment: I get a TypeError like `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'StockIntegrationCode')` on my HTML code; `<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p" style="max-width: 80px;">`

Comment: the property calling `StockIntegrationCode` is undefined. You have something like `something.StockIntegrationCode` in your code and `something` is undefined.

Comment: Normally to clone an object you'd use `let clone = Object.assign({}, this.dataSource.data[index]); this.dataSource.data.push(clone);`